# Flexible 2nd and 3rd column system via CSS2

Tags: css

I have the following setup for a 3 column layout:

```
#column-menu {
float: left;
width: 25%;
}

#column-main {
float: right;
width: 55%;
}

#column-side {
float: left;
width: 20%;
}
```

This code works with the following html:

```
   <div id="column-side">my right side content</div>
   <div id="column-main">my main content</div>
   <div id="column-menu">my sub menu</div>
```

I'm not committed to using floats.  It just so happens that it works with the above structure, except for when nothing is in column-side.  In that case I would like column-main to cover the additional width and not be constrained to 55%. Is there a way to build that kind of flexibility with CSS alone?

Comment: fixing the text in that now...and correct!  the element is still there, but with no html within it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with floats, you will have to reorder your elements:

```css
.column-side {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: #00ffff;
}
.column-menu {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  background: #00ff00;
}
.column-main {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-side">Side</div>
<div class="column-menu">Menu</div>
<div class="column-main">Main</div>
<hr />
<div class="column-side"></div>
<div class="column-menu">Menu</div>
<div class="column-main">Main</div>
```

Comment: This is super close!  How can I get where main starts out in the  middle of the aqua and green elements, but then resorts to only aqua and yellow....so close!

Comment: This is not an adequate solution. Rearranging html so that it doesn't suite the content flow is never an appropriate solution and for what he is looking foat float is just not the correct solution. Float really should not be used for these type of elements. it is for bringing elements out of the natural flow so that things such as text can wrap around an image.

Comment: @blackhawk You mean the order should be: side, main, menu?

Comment: no it should be menu main side.  But if side has no content within in, then it should be just menu main

Comment: @blackhawk I don't understand. Please provide an image of the desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

then in that case you want something like this:
if you remove   `<div id="column-menu" class="align">my sub menu</div>` you will see how it works with proper fluidity.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.align {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
#column-menu {
  width: 25%;
  background: red;
}
#column-main {
  width: 55%;
  background: blue;
}
#column-side {
  width: 25%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="column-side" class="align">my right side content</div>
  <div id="column-main" class="align">my main content</div>
  <div id="column-menu" class="align">my sub menu</div>
</div>
```

A quick explanation of what's going on here:

you are using `table-layout:fixed;` it will automatically equally proportion the child elements with the relative css rule which in this case is `display:table-cell;`

Now because we don't want it to be equal we set the percentages but because of the fixed property when a div is removed the remaining two div's will just span proportionality and auto calculate what there widths should be to still take up the full width of the container.